# C - Assertion failed error

Tags: c, csv, printf

Im writing a cote which generates histogram of a pgm file. It works as intended, but saving results to a .csv file causes assertion failure. Printing results on screen works well, so my error must be somewhere in fprintf function. "histogram.csv" is generated properly without any error, but its empty. How to fix saving it?

```
int counter;
hist_file = fopen("histogram.csv", "w");
if (hist_file = NULL){
    printf("Error opening histogram");
    exit(1);
}
for (i = 0; i <= bright; i++){
    histogram[i] = 0;
}
for (i = 0; i < height; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        for (counter= 0; counter<= bright; counter++){
            if (piksel[i][j] == counter){
                histogram[counter]++;
            }
        }


    }

}

for (i = 0; i <= bright; i++){
    printf( "%d: %d\n",i, histogram[i]);
    fprintf(hist_file, "%d, %d\n", i, histogram[i]);

}
```

Comment: Are you closing the file with `fclose`?

Comment: Make it a habit to compile with warnings activated, for example when using gcc use it like "gcc -Wall <...>".

Comment: typo `if(hist_file = NULL)` -> `if(hist_file == NULL)`

Comment: Taelsin is right, should be (hist_file == NULL) instead of (hist_file = NULL). Thanks

Comment: @filiard Consider marking my answer as the accepted answer. This way it will no longer show up on the "unanswered" section of stack overflow.

Answer (score 3):

Your check to see if `hist_file` is NULL is actually an assignment. You're assigning NULL to your file pointer and since 0 is false you're never going to see `"Error opening histogram"`. After that you're trying to print to a null pointer so you'll get nothing in your file.

You should get into the habit of closing your files too. If you try to close a null file you should get an `EOF` return value, which would give a hint as to where the issue is.